# autoconf configure script broke under a newer Xcode version

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-catalina

I am trying to build the apcupsd package under a newer version of MacOS and Xcode, but the `configure` script supplied with the current version of apcupsd breaks under Xcode 12.4 (though it worked under Xcode 11.2).

The error is `gethostbyname_r` is required.  Now, `configure` tests for this function, and ordinarily it adapts to systems that do not provide it.  On the newer Xcode version, however, `configure` just exits with an error.  I THINK it has something to do with Apple making the `-Werror` setting mandatory.  I've found that I can get a successful build by commenting out the broken test in `configure`, then running it and explicitly passing the flag that `configure` is supposed to set.  But that's not very satisfactory.

Is there is a general way to pass an override to `configure` for the compiler? I tried setting `-Wno-error` in the `CPPFLAGS` and `CFLAGS` environment for `configure`, but the configtest program seems to ignore those.  What seems to be going on is `configure` is seeing that `gethostbyname_r` doesn't exist and sets it to no but then later on still tests for it.  I'm just wondering if there's a flag or something to get past this error, as it seems to me that whatever Apple did to break (or fix) Xcode after version 11.2 would have broken a lot of people's projects.

I am looking for a solution that does not involve modifying the program sources or the Autotools input files.  The project manual is not helpful in this regard.

---

As an update: someone on the apcupsd list told me that this issue is fixed in a later version of Xcode.  I have not tried that yet but when I do if that is what it proves out to be I'll post a followup

Comment: Apple broke a lot of projects' builds when they made `-Werror` the default in Xcode 12, but I didn't think the Autotools were one of the vectors.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there is a general way to pass an override to `configure` for the
> compiler? I tried setting `-Wno-error` in the `CPPFLAGS` and `CFLAGS`
> environment for `configure`, but the configtest program seems to ignore
> those.

If you set the `CFLAGS` or `CPPFLAGS` variable in `configure`'s environment, then not only should `configure` use those flags when it builds test programs, but it should also memorialize the variable so that you don't need to specify it again to `make`.  Indeed, this ...

> What seems to be going on is configure is seeing that
> `gethostbyname_r` doesn't exist and sets it to no

... suggests that it is doing so in your case.

In that event, if it seems to test again later, or else to fail in some other way despite determining that the function is not present, then that suggests a flaw in the project's own autotooling.

> I'm just wondering if there's a flag or something
> to get past this error,

You have already tried the most likely candidate (`CFLAGS`).  Alternatively, you might also be able work around the issue through use of a [cache file](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.70/html_node/Cache-Files.html).  That's still hacky, but I think less so than modifying the `configure` script.  I'm afraid I have no specific guidance on doing this.

> as it seems to me that whatever Apple did to
> break (or fix) Xcode after version 11.2 would have broken a lot of
> people's projects.

It did.  That does not imply that there is a quick or easy solution, though it would be good news if indeed Apple solved the issue in a later version of Xcode.

Comment: configure always tests out with gethostbyname_r not present (no) regardless of CFLAGS or any other variable test setting.  The second test that it blows up on is when it tries testing what version of gethostbyname_r is in use.

Comment: @TedMittelstaedt, any test the `configure` script may be performing for the version of a particular function must be custom to the project.  I cannot speak to what, specifically, such a test may be doing.  Performing such a test under the circumstances seems flawed in the first place, and if that test does not respond to user-specified `CFLAGS` then that is an additional, more subtle flaw.

Comment: @TedMittelstaedt, an additional trick you might try would be to glue the wanted option onto the definition of `CC`, like so: `CC='gcc -Wno-error' ./configure`.  This is a nasty hack, which is why I did not mention it before, but it has a chance of being effective.  More generally, `./configure --help` should give you a comprehensive summary of all the knobs and levers that particular script provides, both standard and custom.

Comment: CC='gcc -Wno-error' ./configure did not work, unfortunately.  So far the only thing I have found that does is to comment out the case switch in configure and pass CPPFLAGS=' -DHAVE_FUNC_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_0' in which gets stuck into the variables.mak file and is then available to the code.  The original authors of apcupsd did have the sense of putting the gethostbyname call variants into a single gethostbyname.c file and the code in there looks for that define and will select the historical gethostbyname() function if it sees it instead of the gethostbyname_r function(s)